# How to iterate through Pandas dataframe from specified row number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am iterating through a dataframe using the df.iterrows() function but am not sure how to specify the row number to run through the dataframe from. I am using a row counter in the initial for loop (below) to search for X within the rows, and once it has found X, I need to loop through the rest of the dataframe to find Y, but without looping through the initial rows that were already looped through when searching for X.

I have tried to achieve this by deleting all rows up to X, but this does not work as it remove entries I need later after the initial X and Y have been found, and I need to find the next X and Y.

```
row_count = 0

for index, row in new_df.iterrows():
        if X in row[2]:
            row_count += 1
            # take information required from row
            
            for visit_index, visit_row in new_df.iterrows():
                if Y in visit_row[2]:
                    # take information required from row
                    
                    # append information to new dataframe
                    
                    break
        else:
            new_df.drop(index, inplace = True)  
            row_count += 1
```

What I want to do instead is use the row_count so that when I find X I can then iterate through the dataframe again from the row where X was present onwards, how can I do this?

Comment: What is X? And what data is stored in row[2] - is this a list in a DataFrame?

Comment: X is a string and row[2] is just strings

Comment: So are you trying to find a substring within a string?

Comment: Yes X is a substring within a sentence, and so is Y

Answer (score 1):

To iterate through only certain rows, take a slice of the DataFrame that contains those rows, and iterate over it.

Separately: keep in mind that a nested inner `for` loop will run all over again, each time through the outer loop. If the goal is to find a "starting point" and do the rest of the iteration from there, then that should be two separate loops: one to find the start point, and one to proceed from there - once.

Thus:

```
for start_index, row in new_df.iterrows():
    if X in row[2]:
        break # `start_index` is the starting point

for index, row in new_df[start_index:].iterrows():
    # process the row
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a much more simple way I believe.

Using the `.loc` function of pandas you could do something like this:

`subset = df.loc[df["YOUR_COLUMN_NAME"].str.contains(X)]`

And this would return the subset of rows in your dataframe that contain X in the column "YOUR_COLUMN_NAME". You haven't specified the name of row[2] but use that instead of "YOUR_COLUMN_NAME"

As an example, my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, "Test1.1"], [2, "Test2.1"]], columns=["ID", "STR"])


x = df.loc[df["STR"].str.contains("Test1")]
print(x)
```

Outputs this:

```
   ID      STR
0   1  Test1.1
```

From here you could take whatever information you needed from the row.